# How to remove critical CSS from the main.css file

Tags: css, asynchronous, optimization, pagespeed, inline-code

I am working hard to imporove page speed. I am using [Critical Path CSS Generator tool](https://jonassebastianohlsson.com/criticalpathcssgenerator/) to identify above-the-fold CSS. Then I inline critical CSS [as suggested](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery), and load the full css asynchronously.

But I end up with a lot of duplicate CSS that way, which is not so optimal. So my question is:

**How to remove critical CSS from the main.css file?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, some of these tools go overboard on the "above the fold" suggestions. If your css is minified, compressed, and all loaded from one file, then it won't slow your page very much. Pulling out specific styles from the sheet for inline "above the fold" styling just makes for messy, unmanageable code that won't be noticeably faster. Pagespeed score is a good reference, but it isn't everything.

Comment: I agree, but the client insists on Google PageSpeed results.

Comment: Then you simply must put the css file in the footer, and have inline styles at the top of the file only for the items visible when the page loads (above the fold). You will need to do this page by page.

Comment: Still, the problem is duplicate code...

Comment: See my first comment. You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it may seem like an anti-pattern, all above-the-fold CSS you inline into your document **SHOULD** be duplicated in your external CSS document. That way, you can make a single site-wide bundle that can be fetched once for your entire site, but that initial page load will be accelerated. While this does result in extra "wasted" KBs upfront, the advantage is that you have a small subset of the necessary CSS available to you as soon as the HTML is sent to the client, reducing the time it takes to render the client's initial view.

Also, to be clear, if you're following this practice correctly, every page on the site will have a different set of above-the-fold css, because every page has different content/tags above-the-fold which would make it impossible to remove the above-the-fold CSS from the full external file (assuming you're concatenating all CSS into one file).

You can read more about the practice of above-the-fold css [here](https://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/).

If you're really concerned about code duplication (though you shouldn't be in this case), you can use cookies to keep track of whether or not a user has visited the site before. If the user has not been before, then you can inline the above-the-fold CSS. If the user has been before, you can assume that the user already has the full CSS file and that the CSS file will be pulled from the browsers cache.

There are a bunch of articles on how unreliable the browser cache is, so my recommendation is that you simply do what you're already doing to satisfy client requirements.

Another thing that should be mentioned is that this practice will largely go away once HTTP/2 becomes more prevalent as subsequent HTTP requests won't be nearly as expensive as they are today. Considering the intensive tooling/effort this practice requires (especially when future proofing against HTTP/2), it may be better (I think it is) to just avoid it completely.

Comment: Why should the above-the-fold CSS be duplicated in the external style sheet?

Comment: Assuming you're following other best practices, your external sheet should be one file with all the CSS for your website.  You'll want that in the browser cache when a user visits another page on your website as the above-the-fold CSS should change depending on what page you're on.

Comment: Gotcha. That's what I assumed, but it wasn't clear from your answer. I edited to clarify. I would argue that "best" is debatable, as that depends on the specifics of what's being served and how often style changes are deployed, and there are multiple approaches to optimization, (and as you cite, HTTP/2 changes the game yet again). Great answer on the whole, though :)

Comment: Your answer is really great and I appreciate it. But assuming I still need to remove some.css from the rest of css, is there a tool to do it?

Comment: There are tools in [CSSNano](http://cssnano.co/) that remove duplicate rules. I'm not sure if it supports multiple files (I know it does a single concatenated file), but you might be able to tweak it for your needs. Also, the cookie solution I mentioned would remove the duplicate CSS for all but the initial rendering.

Answer (score -3):

did you run an `audit` in browser before going to pageSpeed insights

 there you can see suggestions to remove unused css rules and inline performance.
be sure to write whole `style` at the starting of page and avoid these tags in between the page which affects perfomance

and ***importantly***, `inline` should be for `thumbnails` but not for styling the page
example:

```
<p style="padding:2px">something to have some padding</p>
```

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Why is it not an attempt to answer the question? Run an audit, go to pageSpeed insights, follow suggestions to remove inline performance. Sounds to me like it could be an answer?

Comment: i didnt understand ! :-(